# ¿Como calcular el determinante de una matriz de NxN? (JAVA)

Tags: java, array, matrices, matriz, fórmulas-de-matriz

Ando tratando de codificar la manera de calcular el determinante de una matriz de NxN, mas sin embargo no logro llegar a algo en concreto, he estado indagando por Internet, pero solo usan funciones raras, las cuales investigo pero aun así no logro entender su función, si alguien pudiera orientarme le estaria muy agradecido, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Quizás te pueda servir este código:

```
class Test {
    static int determinante;
    static int n_prueba = 4;
    // Matriz genérica:
    // static int matriz_prueba[][] =new int [n_prueba][n_prueba]
    static int matriz_prueba[][] = { { 1, 2, 2, 3 }, { 1, 0, -2, 0 }, { 3, -1, 1, -2 }, { 4, -3, 0, 2 } };
    // Respuesta: -131

    public static int determinanteMatriz(int matriz[][], int n_prueba) {
        int repuesta = 0;
        switch (n_prueba) {
            case 2:
                repuesta = ((matriz[0][0] * matriz[1][1]) - (matriz[1][0] * matriz[0][1]));
                break;
            case 3:
                repuesta = ((matriz[0][0]) * (matriz[1][1]) * (matriz[2][2])
                        + (matriz[1][0]) * (matriz[2][1]) * (matriz[0][2])
                        + (matriz[2][0]) * (matriz[0][1]) * (matriz[1][2]))
                        - ((matriz[2][0]) * (matriz[1][1]) * (matriz[0][2])
                                + (matriz[1][0]) * (matriz[0][1]) * (matriz[2][2])
                                + (matriz[0][0]) * (matriz[2][1]) * (matriz[1][2]));
                break;
            default:
                for (int z = 0; z < matriz.length; z++) {
                    repuesta += (matriz[z][0] * adj(matriz, z, 0));
                }
        }
        return repuesta;
    }

    public static int adj(int matriz[][], int i, int j) {
        int adjunto;
        int matriz1[][] = new int[matriz.length - 1][matriz.length - 1];
        int m, n;
        for (int k = 0; k < matriz1.length; k++) {
            if (k < i) {
                m = k;
            } else {
                m = k + 1;
            }
            for (int l = 0; l < matriz1.length; l++) {
                if (l < j) {
                    n = l;
                } else {
                    n = l + 1;
                }
                matriz1[k][l] = matriz[m][n];
            }
        }
        adjunto = (int) Math.pow(-1, i + j) * determinanteMatriz(matriz1, matriz1.length);
        return adjunto;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        determinante = determinanteMatriz(matriz_prueba, n_prueba);
        System.out.println(determinante);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, solo una duda, el método adj cual es su función?